# iOS: View controllers are not releasing when dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am dismissing the current controller to my root controller like so.

```
  [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, all the view controllers in navigation controllers are not being released (I can tell because methods in the controller classes are being called twice and dealloc method is not being called). I need advice on what to do to figure out why this is occurring. Is there a specific way I need to dismiss the controllers or perhaps something else is occurring. I am using ARC.

Comment: What does Instruments tell you?

Comment: When using ARC it's not granted, that the objects will be released immediately. Do you by any chance hold a strong reference to the controllers somewhere else?

Comment: Are you setting `navigationController = nil;` somewhere? Please post all of your code that references the `navigationController` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to many reasons, but you're most likely holding a strong pointer to the `viewController`s you're popping. One case that happens is if one `viewController` is a `delegate` to another `viewController`, and the `delegate` property is `Strong`, so the two `viewController`s keep a strong pointer to each other.

Make sure there isn't any other object holding a strong pointer to the `viewController`s you're popping.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the possibility of holding a strong reference to the delegate, you should also check any blocks where you use your view controller, and always use the weak reference to that when inside the block.

From Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16):

[image]

Let's assume that you are going to make an HTTP request and display some information about a user that you get from the server on your view controller's view.

```
- (void)requestUserInfo
{
     [self.client makeGETRequest:@"http://example.org/user/1/" usingBlock:^(User *user, NSError *error) {
          if (error) {
              [self.errorView displayWithError:error];
          }
          else {
              self.userView.user = user;
              [self.userView setNeedsLayout];
          }
     }];
}
```

In this case, when user gets bored waiting for the request to return a result and taps "Back" button to just close the page, view controller will not be deallocated until request is done loading and executing the block. You can see it yourself by overriding `dealloc`.

Thus, unless required, always use `__weak` references to `self` inside blocks.

```
- (void)requestUserInfo
{
     __weak UIViewController *weakSelf = self;

     [self.client makeGETRequest:@"http://example.org/user/1/" usingBlock:^(User *user, NSError *error) {
          if (error) {
              [weakSelf.errorView displayWithError:error];
          }
          else {
              weakSelf.userView.user = user;
              [weakSelf.userView setNeedsLayout];
          }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller you are popping out, it is retained from a actually live `viewController`. That's all. You have 2 solutions:

- When you push the `viewController`, create it in place:

  ```
  UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController initWith...];
  [navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
  ```
- The other solution is have a `weak` reference to it:

  ```
  //Property in the interface
  @property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *vc;

  //In the method
  _vc = [UIViewController initWith...];
  [navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
  ```

When the `viewController` will be popped out, having no other references, will be deallocated.

Cheers!